# Youtube save title,image

Tags: .net, youtube

I would like to show a custom list of youtube videos on my website.
I would like to show an image of the video, title and date created.
I would like the user to add the youtube video. He will write the url. How do I get the image, title and datecreated to store in my database when he saves the url? Is there some tutorial?
I am using asp.net C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/). The .NET Documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet).

The API is specifically deigned for developers to interface with Youtube directly, and it should be able to pull video, info, and whatever else you could think of. It may seem daunting and perhaps more than you may need, but it's a great learning experience that will help you learn how to interface with APIs for your projects, both now and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it so when he saves the URL that saves under your database as for example "YoutubeURL" and then add more variables like "YoutubeTitle" "YoutubeDescription" etc.. and just make more forms for him to fill out that will save the data to the database.

I don't think you could make a form extract information from a URL and save to your database.

Comment: When the user adds the url is there no way for me to call for Title, date maybe through a webservice? It would not work if the user had to type in all the information that already exists on the Youtube video.

Comment: I honestly believe that would be illegal as it would bascially be a form that grabs code from another website which is patented. I don't think that would be the best idea to have but its your call.

Comment: I actually thought that YouTube encouraged embedding their videos into another websites. I am not trying to claim the videos as mine.

Comment: This would not be embedding this would actually be grabbing code off of their website.

Comment: I actually do not agree. Where can I ask the YouTube guys about this?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to. And I don't think they would help you to be honest.